# PIV Card Application Validation (PKCS #1 v.1.5 signature padding scheme)

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, smartcard

I am currently writing a .NET API for interacting with a smart card device using PC/SC.  I have most of the API working, but am really getting hung up on the General Authenticate Commands that the card can support.  I am trying to follow the process described in Appendix A.2 (page 25) of [sp800-73-3_Part_2](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-73-3/sp800-73-3_PART2_piv-card-applic-card-common-interface.pdf).

The issue I have is I don't understand what is meant by PKCS #1 v1.5 signature padding, or what the recommended approach would be for generating a challenge that abides by the format guideline.  Any guidance on generating this type of data would be appreciated (using existing .NET API's would be fantastic).

Furthermore, is this format even required for the challenge?  I have tried just sending in a couple of randomly generated bytes but I received back a SW1/SW2 of 0x6A80 (incorrect reference data), so I do realize there are some structural requirements to the data.

Comment: 6A80 is "Incorrect parameters in the data field" according to ISO 7816-4, a more generic error that may not have anything to do with references.

Comment: Dear Chris, I want to write a PIV applet for my smart card. Should I implement whole the signing process on-card, or I can implement the hash calculation off-card and the encryption on-card? I mean is there any specification to mention that whole the process must be implemented on-card to make it a PIV compatible card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PKCS#1 version 1.5 is available as [RFC 2313](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2313). The restrictions in that document to MD2 or MD5 are obviously obsolete. The format is described starting in section 8.1. The block type (BT) is 01, and thus the padding string (PS) is a sequence of constant 0xff bytes. The .NET class S[ystem.Security.Cryptography.RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bt3d03e.aspx) can be used to generate such signatures. As for the rest of the PIV card standard, you are on your own.

Comment: rfc3447 does specify the "mathematically identical" function, including the SHA-1 and SHA-2 hash functions - but the previous RFC, or indeed the original, publicly available PKCS#1 1.5 & 2.1 specifications may be easier to read.